# How do I make all the inputs I recieve go into a data set?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a program that calculates standard deviation and other statistical functions. However, right now, the best bet I have is to manually type out 10 (sometimes more) variables so I can insert them into formulas so I can get the answer. I just want to be able to type a bunch of numbers and have them go into preassigned data sets and then everything more streamlines. Here is my current code

```py
a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10 = input().split() 
mean = (a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10)/10
std_dev = (a1-mean)+(a2-mean)...
```

I haven't finished it yet because I don't want to waste my time doing the code like this if there's a faster function available. I was thinking of doing:

```py
dataset1 = {float(input()), {float(input())}
print(dataset1)
```

but there's two problems with this. First of all, I don't know how many data points I'll be inserting into the program. With this code, I have to copy `{float(input())` and paste that for however many data points I'll have. Also, secondly (and most importantly), this code doesn't work. The code error shows up and it says:

> File "..\Playground\", line 2 
>   print(dataset1)
>           ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import statistics

values = [float(x) for x in input().split()]
mean = statistics.mean(values)
```

Comment: Thank you! Simple and sweet. My answer is solved but I have to wait a few minutes before I can mark it as such.